# perl regex to match all words following a character

Tags: regex, perl

I am no expert with Perl and regex. So here is my question.

How would I write a regex for matching all words in a string to the right of a specified character and retrieve each word separately in Perl?

I don't understand how I could match unspecified number of words and then most importantly retrieve it one at a time? If that is not possible what is my best bet in Perl to get this done?

E.G.: I have a C assignment like `b=var1+var2`. I want to be able to extract `var1` and `var2` if it exists. The important thing is I do not want to match a specific `var1` and `var2`, but any variable after the assignment operator.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please improve your question by including whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: without anyone knowing the exact string in question the answer could be anything — be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`\G`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions)/[`pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) may be useful.

```perl
$_ = 'b=var1+var2';
# force further /g matches to start after the first '='
/=/g;

while (/(\w+)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}

# prints
# var1
# var2
```

Comment: Did you test this? The second regex needs a `/g` modifier. And it's much cleaner to modify `pos` by using `/=/g` after which the assignment isn't necessary.

Comment: @Borodin I did test it, but screwed up re-typing it into SO.  Fixed, and thanks, it is cleaner than manual `pos()=`.

Comment: No need for the `scalar` either. Void context works just as well :)

Comment: Nice work, @ephemient.  I think my brain got caught in a loop that resulted in a rather unsightly (and prolix) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will work for you:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $string = 'b=var1+var2';
my $after  = '=';

say for ( $string =~ /$after(.*)/ )[0] =~ /(\w+)/g;
```

Output:

```
var1
var2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested groups in a regex.  So for example the following regex should match all of the words (defined as \w, but you could tweak that) in your equation after the equals character (delimited by not \w, but you could tweak that as well):

```
=((?<Word>\w*)[^\w]*)*
```