# Perl Regex to match everything after @ character

Tags: regex, perl

I have  a bunch of text files that contain tags referenced by the `@` symbol. For e.g. a note is tagged 'home' if the note contains `@home`.

I am trying to find a Perl Regex that will match everything after the `@` character but not including the @character.

I have this so far `(@\w+)` which successfully matches the whole tag (for .e.g it matches `@home`, `@work` etc) but I cant find a way to modify it so only the characters after the @ character get picked up.

I had a look at this [perl regex to match all words following a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605271/perl-regex-to-match-all-words-following-a-character) but I couldnt seem to work it out from this.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Have a look a "capturing" subpatterns: `/@(\w+)/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Quentin said, `@(\w+)` is the best solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    while (/@(\w+)/g) {
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}
```

If you DO want to match the tag exactly, you can try `(?<=@)\w+` instead. It matches every characters after the `@`, but `@` excluded.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
    while (/(?<=@)\w+/g) {
        print $&, "\n";
    }
}
```

Reference: [Using Look-ahead and Look-behind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `@` so it is outside the capturing group:

```
@(\w+)
```

Comment: I guess his `(` and `)` might be his delimiters. In this case he needs to add an additional group inside.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am using an app called Patterns to test my reg exp and I had tried the solution but the @was still being highlighted in the matched results. When I saw the solution, I decided to just try it in the code and it just worked. Anyway, thanks for all the help. I have to now work out why Patterns still shows the whole word being highlighted.

Comment: Most likely because the highlight shows the matched text, not each capture group.